# 二次元配列のリストから、特定の要素を含むリストを削除する方法について

Tags: python

python初心者・独学者です。ある程度のことはできるようになったのですが、以下の方法が全くつかめずに頭を抱えています。
どなたかよろしくお願いいたします。

```
list_a = [
    { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } ,
    { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } , 
    { "a" : "住所C" , "b" : "小児" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる"} ,
    { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"} ]
```

のような二次元配列のリストがある場合、`"b" == "小児"` の場合は、そのリストを削除して以下の新たなリストを作りたいと思っています。

```
list_b = [
    { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } ,
    { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } , 
    { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"} ]
```

つまり、二次元配列リスト（list_a）内の、特定のリスト`({ "a" : "住所C" , "b" : "小児" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる"})`内の、特定の要素`("b" : "小児")`に当てはまる場合は、リスト全体から、このリストのみを外したいのです。

`for in range ()`文を使ってやってみたのですが、なぜか`out of range`のエラーが出てしまい、途中でストップしていまいます。おそらく、リストが削除されると、その分だけ`range()`の数が減ってしまっていくことが原因と思われますが、それを回避する方法が分かりません。

特に`for`文にこだわっているわけではないので、他にも方法があるのであれば、教えていただけると嬉しいです。

非常にわかりにくい質問となってしまいましたが、御教授いただけると幸いです。

実際に試したコードは以下です。

```
list_a = [
        { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } ,
        { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } ,
        { "a" : "住所C" , "b" : "小児" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる"} ,
        { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"}
        ]

for i in range ( 0 , len(list_a) ) :
    if list_a[i]["b"] == "小児" :
        list_b == list_a.remove (list_a[i]) 

print (list_b)
```

if文の後にelse文が載っていませんが、これを付けるとエラーが出てしまうか、breakすると、Noneが帰ってきます。そもそも、for文でこの問題を解決できるのかどうかかが、分かりません…。

Comment: 念のため実際に試したコードも質問に含めてもらうと回答の参考になると思います。質問は後からでも [編集 できます。 / Pythonは普段使ってないので自信がありませんが、二次元配列の各リストが`{}`でくくられているので、**辞書型** になっているんじゃないかなと思いました。

Comment: cubickさん、御返答ありがとうございます。御指摘の通り、type (list_a[0])をチェックしてみたら、dict型でした。type (list_a)がlist型だったので、すべてがlist型かと思ってしまいました。また、実際に試したコードは稚拙で恥ずかしいのですが、質問蘭に載せてみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リスト内包表記の[後置if](https://qiita.com/y__sama/items/a2c458de97c4aa5a98e7#if%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E5%BE%8C%E7%BD%AEif)で取得できます。

```
`list_b = [x for x in list_a if x["b"] != "小児"]`
```

**追記:**

ご質問のコードでは`i`に0..3が代入されますが、`list_a.remove`すると配列末尾のインデックスが減っていきます。
今回はfor文の最後に`list_a[3]`がなくなっていることが`out of range`エラーが発生する原因です。

`list_b == list_a.remove (list_a[i])`は代入演算子(`=`)ではなく(`==`)比較演算子である点、`list_a.remove`は戻り値を返さない点を考慮して、もう一度コードを読み直すと理解が深まるのではないかと存じます。

```
list_a = [ { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } , { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } , { "a" : "住所C" , "b" : "小児" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる"} , { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"} ]
list_b = []
for x in list_a:
    if x["b"] == "小児":
        continue
    list_b.append(x)

list_b
```

Comment: payanecoさんありがとうございます。やってみたら、できました！リスト内包表記については、書籍で読んだのですが、いまいち分からなかったのと、今回の問題解決につながると思っていなかったので、読み飛ばしていました...。リスト内包表記と後置ifについて勉強させていただきます。

Comment: payanecoさん、もう1つ教えていただけると幸いです。もしこのコードをリスト内包表記ではない方法で記述するとしたら、どのようになるのでしょうか？

Comment: payanecoさん、追加の質問まで御返答いただき、ありがとうございます。1週間悩んでいた点がすっきり解決しました。一人では解決できずに、プログラミングの勉強はやめたい気分になっていましたが、まだ続けれそうです。これからも稚拙な質問をすると思いますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @MuneNiku その他に、`filter()` 関数を使う方法があります。`list(filter(lambda x: 'b' in x and x['b'] != '小児', list_a))` ここで `'b' in x` としているのは、`b` というキーが存在しない場合にエラー(`KeyError`)が発生する事を考慮しています。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。「でたなlambda式めッ！」って感じです。書籍にてlambda式についても記述があったのですが、これまた初学者には敷居が高いものでしたので、あっさり読み飛ばしていました。勉学に励みます！